# Why do we multiply 2 inside the for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

i just came across this code for a lab assignment i am supposed to turn in. What the code does is, it inputs a ".dat" containing a list of words(The first line in the file is the number of data sets). Then it checks the length of each word inside the ".dat" file and sorts it based on the length. Lowest number of letters are first and highest are last. Here is the code.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("words.dat"));

int dataSets = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();

String[] words = new String[dataSets];
//int[] length = new int[dataSets];

for(int a=0; a<dataSets; a++)
{
    words[a] = scan.next();
}

Arrays.sort(words);

for(int a = 0; a < words.length * 2; a++) //what is the purpose of this forloop?
{
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        if(i < words.length - 1)
        {
            if(words[i].length() > words[i + 1].length())
            {
                String temp = words[i];

                words[i] = words[i + 1];

                words[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

for(String word : words)
{
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

I don't get why do we multiply the first for loop by 2.

```
 for(int a = 0; a < words.length * 2; a++)
```

Comment: Quick reading, this look to me to be a not efficient bubble sort. But the complexity is O(n^2) so that explain this mistake, this don't need this `*2` since this is done in two loops

Comment: "I just came across this code for a lab assignment I am supposed to turn in." You mean you stole someone's code for the purposes of turning it in as your own assignment, but you don't understand it?

Comment: [Bubble sort - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). You will found a good explanation of this algoritm with animated examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is an *basic* implementation of a **bubble sort**. You can find an explication of this algorithm on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

In brief, this algorithm will check each pair and inverse it if needed. For having a totally sorted result, they need to parse the array `n*n` ot `n2` and not `n*2` at worst.

By the way, `Arrays.sort(words);` already sort your array.

Comment: i want to sort it by length not alphabetically. so Arrays.sort is not going to sort how i want it to sort

Comment: @Kanna6501 but you just need to implement a Comparator to pass to the [`sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)) to do the job. PS : it indeed will at worst need `n*2` reading, not iteration in the first loop. So this is the sum of every access to the array (the sum of both loops) ;)

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop is needed because it may take several iterations of the loop to fully sort the array.

You could easily show this behaviour by replacing words.length*2 with different hard coded values so you'll see how the sort possibly needs several iterations when the array is written.

words.length*2 ensures that enough iterations have taken place for the array to be correctly sorted... (In a bubble sort the outer loop must iterate once for every element in the array so words.length should be sufficient)